# Android - ListView's height just fits 1 ListView item

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

I am working with Android Studio and designing a layout as below. However, my ListView lv_comics only displays enough space for 1 item. I have tried to set layout_height to fill_parent, but it still does not work. However, when I set layout_height to a specific size, it is OK, but this is not good when I switch to another screen size. Anyone can help me?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout_swiperefresh"
android:background="@color/grey">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Latest Update"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/indigo_main"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/gallery1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Most Popular"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/indigo_main"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>
            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/gallery2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="New Manga"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/indigo_main"
            android:textSize="10dp"/>
        <ListView
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lv_comics" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my layout show.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFIJy.jpg

Comment: `ListView` inside `ScrollView` ...? Not a good idea.

Comment: Listview inside scrollview are not a good idea. To get around this you could add your two views as headers to the listview

Answer (score 0):

try to this to calculate height dynamically

```
public static void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```