# Populating Listview from Database Only Works Once

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to update a listview with user entries into two text inputs. Once the save button is clicked, the user's entry should appear. Based on my code, the listview updates the first time I fill out the two text inputs and I hit save, but the second time I hit save, the listview does not update. Here's my code:

Home.java

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

EditText inputOne;
EditText inputTwo;
MyDBHandler dbHandler; 
Button saveButton; 
MyCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    inputOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputOne);
    inputTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTwo);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    MyDBHandler myDBHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
    Cursor c = myDBHandler.getCursor();
    cursorAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this,c,1);
    ListView notes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notes);
    notes.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);


public void saveClicked(View view) {
    Test test = new Test( inputOne.getText().toString(), inputTwo.getText().toString() );
    dbHandler.addTest(test);
    inputOne.setText("");
    inputTwo.setText("");

    cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

MyDBHandler.java

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database.db";
public static final String TABLE_TEST = "test";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ONE = "one";
public static final String COLUMN_TWO = "two";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEST + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_ONE + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_TWO + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEST);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addTest(Test test){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ONE, test.get_one());
    values.put(COLUMN_TWO, test.get_two());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_TEST, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Cursor getCursor(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ACTIVITIES + " WHERE 1";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    return c;

}
```

}

MyCursorAdapter.java

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, 1);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.one);
    TextView two = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.two);

    String one_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ONE));
    one.setText(one_string);

    String two_string  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_TWO));
    two.setText(two_string);

}
```

}

Test.java

```
public class Test {

private int _id;
private String _one;
private String _two;

public Test(){

}

public Test(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

public Test(String one, String two){
    this._one = one;
    this._two = two;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_one() {
    return _one;
}

public void set_one(String _one) {
    this._one = _one;
}

public String get_two() {
    return _two;
}

public void set_two(String _two) {
    this._two = _two;
}
```

Comment: Why are you recreating the adapter and calling refreshDrawableState()?

You just need to call notifyDatasetChanged() if the underlying data was changed.

Comment: If I don't recreate it, I get an error saying that it cannot resolve the symbol cursorAdapter.

Comment: That's because of scope - you create it as a local variable. Try declaring it as an instance field of the class. (Outside of any method, just inside the class), then initializing it when you have the data.

Comment: I get an error message saying my app has stopped when I do that for some reason. I'll update my code and show the logcat.

Comment: Keep the **instantiation** as it was if it was working, just declare the adapter as a class field, then refer to it when you update the db. Don't initialise everything right away.

Comment: Updated the code. The activity is working now, but the same thing is happening - the first entry will show, but nothing else.

Comment: How is it working at all when the constructor of MyDBHandler is misspelled, and in onCreate() you're calling .getCursor on the dbhandler, when it's a method of CursorAdapter?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I copied my db handler code straight from another question I asked before so that I wouldn't have to reformat it, but I forgot that I changed / added some code. I actually have .getCursor as a method in MyDBHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ListView was populating, but I made the mistake of putting a ListView inside of a ScrollView - so I wasn't able to see the addition of entries. It worked once I used the solution from this: [Android - ListView's height just fits 1 ListView item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041054/android-listviews-height-just-fits-1-listview-item)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to refresh a ListView backed by a Cursor is to call cursorAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(), without needing to recreate and reset the adapter.

So in your saveClicked method you just update the db and let the Adapter know there has been a change.

To do this, you'll need to keep a reference to the adapter as an instance field instead of declaring it as a local variable.